# Android Development: if not and focus

Tags: android

How do i do a if statement but i want like:

```
else if not edittext.getText.toString.contains("hello") then doCode.
```

and how do i setfocus on a component and remove the focus can not really figure that out.

Comment: try to ask only one question at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean editedText = edittext.getText().toString().contains("hello");
if (editedText == true) {
    // do your code here
} else {
    // do your code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry Fred but your code is mostly wrong. contains will return a boolean and you are saving this boolean in a String type variable. 
In the first if condition you are don't have an equals operation you are assigning hello to the variable editText even if it would be you would be comparing strings with == and not with equals wich is a very bad idea...

Comment: sorry Janusz was asleep when I wrote the answer this morning, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

To focus, you can try calling `requestFocus()` on the View object: If editText is a TextView, try: `editText.requestFocus()`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)

To remove focus, call `editText.clearFocus()`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus%28%29)